# Java org.reflections library contains unexpected URLs and produced 0 results

Tags: java

I've recently used Reflections library (org.reflections) for my framework. This framework is scanning classes and invoking some methods. For new package (not inner) is creating new Reflections instance:

```
new Reflections(path,
     new ResourcesScanner(),
     new TypeAnnotationsScanner(),
     new SubTypesScanner());
```

Today, when I wanted to add second package with different name (not inside first package), created for it new instance of Reflections. Sadly, if I tested it, the first instance successfully scanned classes:

```
Reflections took 123 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 31 keys and 44 values
```

But the second didn't:

```
Reflections took 180 ms to scan 15 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values
```

As you can see, the second reflections did two things, which I don't know why. It added 14 other URLs and result was 0 keys and 0 values. Result of this was that second reflections didn't found any classes and my second program was not working.

I did debug, there were 15 urls including the first one, but NOT THE SECOND PACKAGE (which I used now). So I think that the second instance shared some URLs with the first and other used in other third-party libraries.

My question is, do you know where can be the problem and how can I make the second reflections only scan the second package? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand at all what you are doing or trying to do. Maybe write the code that you are running?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to run Reflections library (org.reflections) on two different packages, but two different Reflections instances.

Comment: Important thing i didn't typed is that the second reflecttions creation is invoked in different jar file.